# Typo3 wrap image elements

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have a site running `Typo3`.

If I add an element of the type `image` or `textpic`, I want the `<img>`-tag to be surrounded by a couple of divs. So, i thought, i have to use `typoscript` for that.

So I added:

```
tt_content {
    image.20.wrap = <div class="hello">|</div>
```

}

I can see it in the object-browser, but it isn't displayed in the frontend. From what i got so far, is, that for image and textpic I have to override this `image.20`.

Typoscript:

```
tt_content {    
    uploads.wrap = <div class="tro-uploads-wrap">|</div>
}

tt_content {    
    table.wrap = <div class="tro-table-wrap">|</div>
}

tt_content.image.20.imageStdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a wrap around the whole element can be done via:

```
tt_content.image.20.stdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>
```

If you just want to wrap the image it self, use

```
tt_content.image.20.imageStdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>
```

Comment: tried it, still no effect on the dom :/
i added the typoscript part in my description

Comment: I have the same issue with typo3 6.2... what version are u using?